# How can I test the Google Translate API with cURL?

Tags: api, curl, google-translate

I'm attempting to use cURL to test the Google Translate API to see if it will suit my needs. But when I run this

```
$ curl https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=mykeyhere&source=en&target=de&q=Hello
```

I receive this in response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: q",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   },
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: target",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "target"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: q"
 }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

(Also, I understand StackOverflow may not be the best place for the question. I am happy to request that this question be moved to a different StackExchange site if someone will be kind enough to suggest an appropriate site for this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this NPM package to test, and once I enabled billing in the Google Developer Console, things worked: https://www.npmjs.org/package/google-translate